# MySQL information_schema.tables is not creating new entries

Tags: php, mysql, linux, mysqli, information-schema

I have a simple Droplet setup in Digital Ocean and I installed MySQL in it. I also installed PhpMyAdmin for UI control of the databases.

My problem is when I try to import/create Database through PhpMyAdmin or using script (php), the `information_schema.tables` does not create new entries of the currently imported/created database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your user privileges by witch you are connecting phpmyadmin or your php script, manage that user permissions and add privilege for creating database.